# Is it possible to make Django send data over tls protocol?

Tags: django, python-2.7, ssl

I am currently working on a web project in django and there is a requirement to ensure the safety of transmitting data over a network (passwords, usernames etc.).
I've read on owasp cheat sheet about authenication that for safety reasons all passwords should be sent from a client to a server over tsl protocol.
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet#Transmit_Passwords_Only_Over_TLS_or_Other_Strong_Transport

Django framework sends these over http protocol. Is it possible to make django send it over tsl or work around it in another way?

Comment: This isn't up to Django at all; it's entirely up to how you're serving your site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a Django application on the Internet, it's usually looking something like this:

```
[Django Application] <-> [uWSGI] <-> [nginx] <-> [web browser]
```

You can use different components, e.g. Gunicorn instead of uWSGI or Apache instead of nginx.

The thing is, you simply configure the webserver (Apache or nginx or whatever) with an SSL certificate and listen for https instead of http.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using Django `runserver` command for server your app over HTTP. It is absolutely not made for production and is a really HTTP (only) server for development.

For serve your app across SSL/TLS, you must use a frontend as described in [henrikstroem's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170612/is-it-possible-to-make-django-send-data-over-tls-protocol#answer-32170885)